# Github code vault: how to check if a repo is classified as active

Tags: git, github

What does "active repository" exactly mean for the Github vault snapshot?

Is there a list of requirements to classify a repository as "active"?

[Github vault project](https://archiveprogram.github.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a clear definition of "active", but the [FAQ](https://archiveprogram.github.com/faq/) offers some elements of an answer:

> On February 2, 2020 at 2 pm PT, we will begin snapshotting all of GitHub’s public repositories that have been active within recent months. Additionally, a team of chosen experts and advisors will identify important inactive projects to be added to the archive. **To ensure your repository is included, update your repository, clean up your README, and push a commit sometime before February 2**.

(emphasis mine)